# Bond strength of carbon compounds

Tags: bond, carbonyl-compounds, ionic-compounds, covalent-compounds

I read online that C=O is more stronger than C=N and the reason behind this was, 'Since bond between C and O is more polar hence it will have a slightly higher ionic nature than C and N. As we know ionic bonds are stronger than covalent bond hence C=O bond is stronger.' 
Then I tried to find the bond strenght between C-O and C-N by applying the same logic but the result turned out to be the opposite of what I had calculated. According to factual data C-N is stronger than C-O. Can anyone please explain me what's wrong in my reasoning and whether it's right or not.

Comment: The data is right..

Comment: That doesn't answer my question ^^"

Comment: This page seems to contradict your statement.. http://www.wiredchemist.com/chemistry/data/bond_energies_lengths.html

Comment: @NikhilAnand I gave this statement based on the data given here: https://forums.studentdoctor.net/threads/c-o-c-n-and-ionic-bond-strength.1282556/

Comment: And I totally agree with the data given by you cause I referred some other sources also and it matches your data :)

Comment: It's not an ionic bond...

Comment: @zhe i never said that it's an ionic bond. I was just mentioning about the ionic nature in the bond.

Comment: Just because there's charge separation doesn't mean you should start thinking there's anything ionic about the bond at all...